# In Reactjs why 'history' of undefined error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, runtime-error

I have this functional component.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function ProfileForm(props) {
const form = useForm();
const {
register,
handleSubmit,
errors
  } = form;
const history = useHistory(); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined 
......
    }
```

Why this error? Btw, I installed react-router-dom. How to use history in the functional components?

Update more code:-

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:8080/profile', profile)
  .then(res => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/OnSubmit",
      state: {
        response: res.data,
        msgVariant: "success"
      }
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    // handle this error
    history.push({
      pathname: "/OnSubmit",
      state: {
        response: error.message,
        msgVariant: "danger"
      }
    })
  })
```

Later I am using history as above?

Comment: Are you trying to use `history` anywhere later in your code? if yes please show the code.

Comment: pls check more code where I am using history

Comment: Are you sure the error is `'history' of undefined error` and not `history is not defined`? If it's the latter then history is out of scope.

Comment: Hello, please add which version of react-router-dom you are using and the piece of code where you use the routes that involves ProfileForm component.

Comment: Is this being rendered from a `<Route>`?

Comment: Version "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",

Comment: No, it is not rendered from any Route yet. But once I fix this error, I have to use some routing to route to the  OnSubmit page. But I couldn't go process due to this error.

Comment: ProfileForm component must be inside a Parent Router Component for history to work

Comment: @SumanBarick Looks like after adding the parent router the error is gone. It doesn't give any error now. Thanks a lot. If u wish u can comment as an answer.

Comment: Glad to know @masiboo and thanks. I will put it as a comment as a reference to whoever stumbles upon this issue in future. This is a very common one. Please comment on my answer if I need to change anything and please accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be it a functional component or a class component, for router history to work the component must be a child of the Router component.

We need to do something like this,

```
    import {
      BrowserRouter as Router
    } from "react-router-dom"

    //and then, wherever we want to use `history`, we need to have it nested under this <Router />
   <Router>
    <SomeOtherComponent>
       ...
          <ComponentWhereWeWantToUseHistory />
       ...
    </SomeOtherComponent>
  </Router>
```

I hope it helps. Happy coding :)